# WITH vs nested SELECT or maybe INSERT INTO @temp?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Since I am about to write complex query with many union alls, inner joins, I would like to choose the best structure of the code for the sake of clarity. Here are two queries which lead to the same results. What is the convention? Do you recommend using nested SELECTs or WITH statement or maybe INSERT INTO temp tables? Can you direct me to any publication how to use TAB, parentheses etc.

**First Query**

```
WITH BigPictureQuery AS 
    (
    SELECT BottomLevelQuery FROM TabA AS a
    )
SELECT Something FROM BigPictureQuery
```

**Second Query**

```
SELECT Something FROM 
    (
    SELECT BottomLevelQuery 
    FROM TabA AS a
    ) 
    AS BigPictureQuery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of using non recursive `CTE` i find over the `subquery` is it can be `referred` more then once with in the `CTE` scope.

Also it is more readable than subquery. Performance wise both the methods is going to be similar.

Ex: `CTE`

```
WITH BigPictureQuery AS 
    (
    SELECT BottomLevelQuery FROM TabA AS a
    )
SELECT Something FROM BigPictureQuery  A
join BigPictureQuery B on a.Something =b.Something 
join BigPictureQuery C on a.Something =C.Something 
..
```

to do the same thing with `subselect` the query will be like

```
SELECT Something FROM 
(
SELECT BottomLevelQuery 
FROM TabA 
) 
AS A
join 
(
SELECT BottomLevelQuery 
FROM TabA 
) 
AS A on a.BottomLevelQuery =b.BottomLevelQuery 
join 
(
SELECT BottomLevelQuery 
FROM TabA 
) 
AS C on a.BottomLevelQuery =C.BottomLevelQuery 
...
```

Clearly `CTE` is more readable here